# Problems with ExpandableListView in a ParallaxScrollView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to fill an ExpandableListView with a custom adapter.

This is how I fill it, in my Activity :

```
 private void fillSeasons(Video video) {
        if(video instanceof Series) {
            Series series = (Series) video;
            HashMap<Season, List<Episode>> map = new HashMap<Season, List<Episode>>();
            for(Season season:series.getSeasons()) {
                map.put(season, season.getEpisodes());
            }
            SeasonAdapter adapter = new SeasonAdapter(this,series.getSeasons(),map);
            testSeason.setText(adapter.getGroupCount() + " seasons"); //A TextView to test adapter
            listSeason.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else {
            layoutSeasons.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

This is my custom adapter :

```
public class SeasonAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private static final String LOG = SeasonAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private static String PREFIX_IMAGE = TmdbService.PREFIX_IMAGE+TmdbService.POSTER_SIZES[3];

    private Context context;
    private List<Season> seasons; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<Season, List<Episode>> episodes;

    public SeasonAdapter(Context context, List<Season> seasons,
                                 HashMap<Season, List<Episode>> episodes) {
        this.context = context;
        this.seasons = seasons;
        this.episodes = episodes;
        String msg = "Episodes:\n";
        for(Season season:episodes.keySet()) {
            msg += "Season "+season.getNumber()+" ("+season.getId()+")\n";
            for(Episode episode:episodes.get(season)) {
                msg+=episode.getNumber()+"-"+episode.getTitle()+"\n";
            }
        }
        Log.d(LOG,msg);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        Log.d(LOG,"getChild at position "+childPosititon+" of group "+groupPosition);
        return this.episodes.get(this.seasons.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Log.d(LOG,"getChildId: "+childPosition);
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_episode_item, null);
        }
        final Episode episode = (Episode) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        Log.d(LOG,"childView:"+ episode.getTitle());

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.season_text);

        txtListChild.setText(episode.getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        Log.d(LOG,"getChildrenCount: "+this.episodes.get(this.seasons.get(groupPosition)).size());
        return this.episodes.get(this.seasons.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        Log.d(LOG,"getGroup at position "+groupPosition);
        return this.seasons.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        Log.d(LOG,"getGroupCount: "+this.seasons.size());
        return this.seasons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        Log.d(LOG,"getGroupId: "+groupPosition);
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_season_group, null);
        }
        final Season season = (Season) getGroup(groupPosition);
        Log.d(LOG,"groupView:"+ context.getString(R.string.season)+" "+season.getNumber());

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.season_title);
        lblListHeader.setText(context.getString(R.string.season)+" "+season.getNumber());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        Log.d(LOG,"hasStableIds: false");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Log.d(LOG,"isChildSelectable: true");
        return true;
    }


}
```

And my problem is : the parameter "groupPosition" in method getGroupView is always "0", but the getGroupCount returns the correct value (6 in my case).

This is the output :

```
09-29 21:38:38.070    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ Episodes:
    Season 1 (3572)
    1-Chute libre
    2-Le choix
    3-Dérapage
    4-Retour aux sources
    5-Vivre ou survivre
    6-Bluff
    7-Le fruit défendu
    Season 2 (3573)
    1-Traqués
    2-Chasse à l'homme
    3-Alibi
    4-Au fond du gouffre
    5-Nouveau départ
    6-Règlements de comptes
    7-Poisson lune
    8-Appelez donc Saule
    9-Seuls au monde
    10-Introspection
    11-Nouvelle donne
    12-Vie et mort
    13-Effet papillon
    Season 3 (3575)
    1-No Mas
    2-Caballo Sin Nombre
    3-I.F.T.
    4-Green Light
    5-Retour aux affaires
    6-Le Camping-Car
    7-Vendetta
    8-Prise de pouvoir
    9-Kafkaïen
    10-La Mouche
    11-Société écran
    12-Demi-mesures
    13-Pleine mesure
    Season 4 (3576)
    1-Le Cutter
    2-Snub 38
    3-Motivations
    4-Les Points importants
    5-Nouveau Job
    6-Guerre froide
    7-Négociations
    8-Frères et Partenaires
    9-Incontrôlables
    10-Salud
    11-Seul contre tous
    12-Échec
    13-Mat
    Season 0 (3577)
    1-
    2-
    3-
    4-
    5-
    6-
    Season 5 (3578)
    1-Vivre libre ou mourir
    2-Madrigal
    3-Nouveaux labos
    4-Cinquante et un
    5-Un plan presque parfait
    6-Divergence
    7-Heisenberg
    8-Un nouveau jour se lève
    9-Le prix du sang
    10-Enterré
    11-Confessions
    12-Comme un chien enragé
    13-Règlement de compte à Tohajiilee
    14-Seul au monde
    15-L'origine du mal
    16-Revenir et mourir
09-29 21:38:38.070    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.070    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ hasStableIds: false
09-29 21:38:38.070    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.070    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.080    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.080    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroup at position 0
09-29 21:38:38.080    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ groupView:Season 0
09-29 21:38:38.080    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.080    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroup at position 0
09-29 21:38:38.090    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ groupView:Season 0
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroup at position 0
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ groupView:Season 0
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroup at position 0
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ groupView:Season 0
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroup at position 0
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ groupView:Season 0
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroup at position 0
09-29 21:38:38.130    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ groupView:Season 0
09-29 21:38:38.140    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.140    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroup at position 0
09-29 21:38:38.140    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ groupView:Season 0
09-29 21:38:38.140    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.140    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroup at position 0
09-29 21:38:38.140    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ groupView:Season 0
09-29 21:38:38.150    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroupCount: 6
09-29 21:38:38.150    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ getGroup at position 0
09-29 21:38:38.150    4199-4199/com.vwuilbea.mymoviecatalog D/SeasonAdapter﹕ groupView:Season 0
```

I don't know if the problem come from my layouts, in case this is it :

```
 <RelativeLayout >
     <!-- ... -->
     <ParallaxScrollView >
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- Season layout -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_seasons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/minimum_margin"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_location">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/test_season"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/label_seasons"/>

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/season_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/test_season"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

       </RelativeLayout>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ParallaxScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_season_group.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/season_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle_medium_size_details"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, my list_episode_item.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/episode_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle_medium_size_details"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've found my problem's origin :

My ExpandableListView is into a ParallaxScrollView, so if it set the list layout_height to "wrap_content" or "match_parent", it doesn't work (I don't know exactly why?!). I've tried to set the layout_height to 200dp, and it works fine !

But somebody could tell me why ? And how can I do it properly ?

(Do I have to open a new thread to ask this question ?)

Answer (score 0):

If the group position is always 0, it means that you are storing all episodes in the same Season.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately this is not the cause of my problem, cf my edited question.